# Which device uses which driver under Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers

How can I find out or list that what drivers the devices in my pc use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
lspci -k
```

Comment: This only works for PCI devices, right?

Comment: Correct. If youre looking for usb devices, then dmesg as mentioned by Shadur is probably the best way. However you can run `lsmod` and see which modules are in use by the 'used by' counter

Answer (score 5):

`dmesg` and `/var/log/kern.log` or wherever your distro leaves kernel log messages is your best bet. Most drivers when they're loaded leave a friendly message in the kernel log detailing that they were loaded and what kind of hardware they found themselves attached to, like:

```
[    2.319928] Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.3.20-k2-NAPI
[    2.320078] Copyright (c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation.
[    3.954481] PCI: Setting latency timer of device 0000:02:01.0 to 64
[    4.283544] e1000: 0000:02:01.0: e1000_probe: (PCI:66MHz:32-bit) 00:50:56:99:00:1a
[    4.324951] e1000: eth0: e1000_probe: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
```